Hidden Markov Model of a stationary Markov chain is a stationary process.
Let $X=(X_i)_{i \ge 1}$ be an irreducible Markov chain started in its stationary distribution, and $Y=(Y_i)_{i \ge 1}$ be such that $Y_i=\phi(X_i)$ for an arbitrary function $\phi$.
Note that $X$ is a stationary stochastic process - satisfying $\mathbb{P}(X_1=x_1,...,X_n=x_n)=\mathbb{P}(X_{1+j}=x_1,...,X_{n+j}=x_n)$ for all $n,j,x_1,...,x_n$.
In general, $Y$ is not necessarily a Markov chain; for example, if $X$ is the chain on $\{-1,1,2\}$ that deterministically cycles through $-1 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow ...$, and $\phi(x)=x^2$, then $Y$ has state space $\{1,4\}$ but deterministically cycles $1 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow ...$ and we see clearly that the Markov property is violated.
However, I've been told without proof that $Y$ is in fact also a stationary stochastic process. Is this correct, and how can one rigorously prove this?
I can imagine a simple "proof" that goes:
$$\mathbb{P}(Y_1=y_1,...,Y_n=y_n)=\mathbb{P}(\phi(X_1)=y_1,...,\phi(X_n)=y_n)$$
$$=\mathbb{P}(\phi(X_{1+j})=y_1,...,\phi(X_{n+j})=y_n)=\mathbb{P}(Y_{1+j}=y_1,...,Y_{n+j}=y_n)$$
However, without injectivity of $\phi$ I'm struggling to see how that middle equality can be formalised.

$\mathbb{P}(Y_1 = y) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 \in \phi^{-1}(y)) = \mathbb{P}(X_n \in \phi^{-1}(y)) = \mathbb{P}(Y_n = y)$, for example. Essentially if $\phi$ isn't injective then you can still work with measuralbe sets (here, the preimages) instead.

Of course, that makes sense thanks
